# What's the replacement for passing an array to the first argument of app.get()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In the past, you could have done something like this:

```
app.get(['/', '/dashboard'], (req, res, next) => { ... });
```

in order to have multiple routes using the same route handler.

Several Stack Overflow answers indicate that this behavior is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Aside from an ugly regex or a semi-hack like putting the function into a variable and passing it to 2 distinct `app.get()` calls, is there an elegant alternative to just passing an array as the first argument?

Comment: Why do you consider passing it a function with 2 .get calls a semi-hack?

Comment: Because passing an array of strings where you want the same action applied on two strings is sort of a convention in node. And I consider it a semi hack for the same reason I don't have to cache a value in a variable before I return it. It adds verbosity for no good reason.

Comment: ahh interesting.. Just curious as I also wonder about this and have tried a bunch of ways. This is the cleanest way i've found to dealt with it `router.get('/', getRoute); router.get('/:page', getRoute);` .. and I made 2 calls because the index returns as `/` and doesn't get picked up by the `/:page` call. And yes i know this is what you are saying you don't want to do.

Comment: I suppose you create two routes, that call the same function

Comment: @adeneo Indeed I can, but I want to avoid that (as mentioned in the question).

Comment: I think the answer to this is: one of the two methods you (and by extension I) mentioned as being less elegant than the array solution. @express-devs GIVE ME BACK MY ARRAYS! </ranty-comment>

Comment: The yeoman generator we use creates something like: `app.get('/:url(api|assets|...)', function());` to route multiple urls to the same controller.

Comment: [Interestingly this was never meant to be supported in the first place](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/1549).

Another suggestion by the author is to use `rewrite` - `app.use(rewrite('/', '/dashboard'))`

Comment: Hmm...couldn't you just create a function that has the behaviour you'd like? e.g. `function app_get(app, list, f) { for (i in list) { app.get(i, f); } }`.  I agree that it's annoying they removed functionality, but they probably figured that most people would just write app.get multiple times and create named functions/routers for repeated handlers.  BTW, I cannot repeat enough that I agree that it's strange they'd remove something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var originalExpressGet = app.get;

app.get = (function() {
  var expressApp = app;
  function turnToArray(args){
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
      array.push(args[i]);
    }
    return array;
  }
  return function(routes, callback) {
    var args = turnToArray(arguments);
    if(args.length <= 1){
      return originalExpressGet.apply(app, arguments);
    }

    if(!Array.isArray(routes)){
      routes = [routes];
    }
    args.shift();
    routes.forEach(function(route){
      originalExpressGet.apply(app, [route].concat(args));
    });
  }
  return app;
}());
```

That way you are still using express's app.get, but it allows you to use [] for multiple routes. For example, this works:

```
app.get(['/', '/same'], function(req, res){
  res.send(true);
});
```

And so does this:

```
app.get('/another route', function(req, res){
  res.send(true);
});
```